# Meteor Email - Synced Cron - Exception in setTimeout callback: TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTime' of undefined`

Tags: javascript, email, meteor, cron

Using the percolate:synced-cron package, I'm trying to schedule sending an email for a specific time in the future.  I insert a future task into the db, but I get this error `Exception in setTimeout callback: TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTime' of undefined`

```
db.future_tasks.find({}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : "t35s5Daj7iwNeW9gm",
    "to" : "niko.tzikas@gmail.com",
    "from" : "niko.tzikas@gmail.com",
    "subject" : "wassup",
    "text" : ISODate("2015-07-22T19:25:32.781Z"),
    "date" : ISODate("2015-07-22T19:25:32.781Z")
}




I20150722-15:22:50.339(-4) (synced-cron-server.js:52) SyncedCron: scheduled "EguDR6bFxKNECZAXF" next run @Wed Jul 22 2015 15:23:10 GMT-0400 (EDT)
I20150722-15:23:10.266(-4) (synced-cron-server.js:52) SyncedCron: Starting "EguDR6bFxKNECZAXF".
I20150722-15:23:10.269(-4) (synced-cron-server.js:52) SyncedCron: Removed "EguDR6bFxKNECZAXF
I20150722-15:23:10.271(-4) (synced-cron-server.js:52) SyncedCron: Finished "EguDR6bFxKNECZAXF".
I20150722-15:23:10.279(-4)? Exception in setTimeout callback: TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTime' of undefined
I20150722-15:23:10.279(-4)?     at scheduleTimeout (packages/percolatestudio:synced-cron/synced-cron-server.js:238:1)
I20150722-15:23:10.280(-4)?     at Object.SyncedCron._laterSetTimeout (packages/percolatestudio:synced-cron/synced-cron-server.js:228:1)
I20150722-15:23:10.280(-4)?     at scheduleTimeout (packages/percolatestudio:synced-cron/synced-cron-server.js:206:1)
I20150722-15:23:10.280(-4)?     at packages/percolatestudio:synced-cron/synced-cron-server.js:248:1
I20150722-15:23:10.280(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150722-15:23:10.281(-4)?     at packages/meteor/timers.js:6:1
I20150722-15:23:10.281(-4)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
```

I tried making the date a string, but it makes no difference.  If I try actually emailing the task (which works without SyncedChron) like:

```
Email.send({
    from: details.from,
        to: details.to,
        subject:new Date(),
    text: details.date
    //date: details.date
});
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Object Wed Jul 22 2015 15:24:46 GMT-0400 (EDT) has no method 'replace'
```

http://richsilv.github.io/meteor/scheduling-events-in-the-future-with-meteor/

https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron

Answer (score 0):

It is [a bug in the package](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron/issues/41). A fix is listed on that link and apparently included in [this package](https://atmospherejs.com/orphan/synced-cron).